# FFMPEG: Remove entirely blue frames from a video

Tags: ffmpeg, editing, color

I'm trying to help my father who digitizes various video and audio tape formats.
It appears that occasionally digitization hard- and software does not receive enough information from a frame and the output result turns out to be a solid blue frame.

I'm a complete newbie in this type of thing but I found out FFMPEG might help me. I want to write a command that takes input .mp4 video, detects frames with a certain hex color and removes them from the output video (frames should be completely ignored/skipped/trimmed, audio must be synced as well).

I've tried using free ChatGPT (I know, I know..) but no luck so far.
I'm not a power user by any means.

Help please!